# Array formula to join header values in a Google Sheet when row values equal "yes"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206161/searching-for-a-arrayformula-that-looks-up-and-joins-header-titles) question but was not able to get it to work for me. Since it is already answered and from an year ago I felt it best to post a new question.

I have a sample sheet at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EqNfTWcNFgkv2gdovnH7JpqU9V2HG5Vkoup8bhNqI7k/edit#gid=0

In `F1` I want an array formula that will join the values of `B1:E1` if `B2:E = "yes"`.

Column `G` has the expected output.

This is what I came up with but it's giving error:

```
={
    "output";
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(
            A2:A = "",
            ,
            IF(
                B2:E = "yes",
                TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, B1:E1),
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out

```
=index(substitute(trim(transpose(query(transpose(if(B2:E<>"yes",,B1:E1)),,9^9)))," ",", "))
```

If the header contain spaces, use:

```
=index(substitute(substitute(trim(transpose(query(transpose(if(B2:E<>"yes",,substitute(B1:E1," ","❄️"))),,9^9)))," ",", "),"❄️"," "))
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:E="yes", B1:E1&",", )),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]